# Windows 10 File Explorer shows a blank white screen

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Occasionally the lower part of Windows 10 File Explorer becomes just a blank white screen.
I have tried using `sfc /scannow`, `DISM` but it didn't have any effect.
The only way to reset this is to do a restart and sometimes restarting `explorer.exe` process helps but it doesn't always work. I think also dwm.exe (desktop window manager) might be related to this bug.

OS version and build: Windows 10 22H2, 19045.2546, Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0
[image]

Comment: The problem is too vague. Try a heavy tool : [Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue. Try opening CMD and typing `taskkill -f -im explorer.exe` and then `explorer`

Answer (score -2):

try scanning your PC with malwarebytes and see if there's any malware hampering your system. If so then take the required action against the malware, reboot the PC after deleting the detected threats(mostly recommended by malwarebytes itself). After reboot see if system is working ok?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i'm new to this platform, and dont know workarounds. But thanks for pointing these things, i'll ttry to correct the answer.